# Using continue with condition in php

Tags: php, continue

```
$condition1[0] = 2;
$condition1[1] = 3;
$condition2[0] = 3;
$condition2[1] = 2;
$condition2[2] = 1;

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<2;$j++){
        if($condition1[$j] == $condition2[$i]){
            $permission = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if($permission){
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to check two arrays.
"success" must be echoed when there's a different value in `$condition2`
in this case there's only one difference which is `$condition2[2] = 1` so "success" must be echoed only once, but it happens twice!

and also if I use `continue;` like the example above, does it skip the whole inner `for()`?

Comment: perhaps `array_intersect` would be of more use, rather than doing multiple loops? As well, you could probably fix your multiple-output problem by moving the `if(){echo}` snippet to the bottom of the script, OUTSIDE of the `for($i...)` loop.

Comment: You probably want `break`, not `continue`. `continue` stops the current iteration, `break` exits the whole loop.

Comment: I used `break`, but the number of 'success' was zero

Comment: no idea what you are trying to achieve. can explain ?

Comment: I know it's confusing, because it's part of something bigger and I can't write it all here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all what you care about is finding one difference the below code should do the trick:

```
$permission = false;
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<2;$j++){
        if($condition1[$j] != $condition2[$i]){
            $permission = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} 

    if($permission){
        echo 'success';
    }
```

Comment: Explain to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I changed the structure of the code, it worked. I think I had a logical problem, there was nothing wrong with the code. Anyway thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

First as Barmar points out, you might want to use break and not continue.

Second, in your code, $permission is never set to true. So, it is not surprising that it does not echo 'success'.

Maybe what you want is this (althgout i must admit I am not sure to know what you want to achieve):

```
$condition1[0] = 2;
$condition1[1] = 3;
$condition2[0] = 3;
$condition2[1] = 2;
$condition2[2] = 1;

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $permission = true;
    for($j=0; $j<2;$j++){
        if($condition1[$j] == $condition2[$i]){
            $permission = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($permission){
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

Comment: `$permission` is a global variable with the default value of `true`

Comment: sure but in the first iteration of the outer loop, $permission is set to false and since it is never set back to true, it will not echo 'success'

Comment: I added `else{ $permission = ture; }` after if, then I had 2 'success'

Comment: It is hard to tell you what to do without knowing what you want to achieve. I suggest you tell us a bit more first.

Comment: I changed the structure of the code, it worked. I think I had a logical problem, there was nothing wrong with the code. Anyway thanks for your help ;)